# Using gxine_client to get and set value playlist.repeat for running gxine

Tags: video, bash, shell, javascript, xine

I would like to know how to use the gxine javascript interface from bash shell.

I want to have a bash shell script read out value of running gxine, 
set things like <s>playlist repeat/loop option</s>, change aspect ratio, 
<s>change/revert to full screen</s>, read out existing value, and such, all from a shell script.

man gxine tells me to use "--command TEXT" where TEXT is javascript.
gxine-{version}/doc/Keybindings-HOWTO has a list of values I am supposed to be able to change,
however it does not seem to work. I think I am using it the wrong way.

**Update:** After fiddling around a while, figured out how to load the playlist.

```
# load playlist from file
gxine_client 'playlist_load("/mnt/dir/playlist.asx");playlist_play(1);'

# set to repeat whole palylist 
gxine_client 'playlist.repeat.v = true ;'

# set to randomly play songs on playlist
gxine_client 'playlist.random.v = true ;'

# mute sound
gxine_client 'ao_mute.v = true ;'
# unmute sound
gxine_client 'ao_mute.v = false ;'

# toggle fullscreen 
gxine_client 'vo_fullscreen.v = true ;'
```

Still looking for ways to read out values, like total time of song, number of songs on playlist,etc ...

Comment: Figured out how to load the playlist.
<code>
 gxine_client 'playlist_load("/mnt/dir/playlist.asx");playlist_play(1);'
<code>